# Flutter for web - GestureDetector around RaisedButton

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

For context: https://dartpad.dev/c9689b40a5402e12538c726b5c0380ff

I have a `GestureDetector` (that has some specific business logic) that listens to single taps and has a `child` as parameter.

In a specific location, I want this `child` widget to look like a button. However, using a real button widget apparently skips the `onTap` of GestureDetector.

At first I thought that `onTapCancel` would then kick in, but for `onTapCancel` to trigger the widget needs to be 'long pressed'.

Any suggestions on how to solve this? (Using `IgnorePointer` around the child doesn't work.)

Comment: so you want to see the ripple/splash effect?

Comment: not only that. I want the behavior of a button without the need for an `onPressed` on that button. I want the onPressed to be triggered by the parent. You can see that in the interactive example at the top of the question.

Comment: In you GestureDetector, you have onTap function where you can do your functionality. 
So showing like a button, you need to have Card() or Container() and design accordingly.

And set a flag and check condition if pressed then show or change behavior of that gesture detector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[AbsorbPointer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AbsorbPointer-class.html)

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
        child: AbsorbPointer(child : child),
        onTap: () {
          print('tap');
          onTap();
        },
        onTapCancel: () {
          print('tapCancel');
        });
  }
```